# What is the meaning of the segment name of a domain index?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, full-text-search, disk-space

I want to know the space used by one of my indexes. I query the view `DBA_SEGMENTS` to do it:

```
SELECT segment_name, sum(bytes) FROM dba_segments WHERE segment_name LIKE '%INDEX_NAME%' GROUP BY segment_name;
```

I got this response:

```
DR$INDEX_NAME$X 1369440256
DR$INDEX_NAME$I 1586495488
DR$INDEX_NAME$R 65536
```

What is the meaning of the prefix `DR` and the suffixes `X`, `I` and `R` in the name of my segments? What is the real size of my index : 1369440256 B, 1586495488 B or 2956001280 B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Oracle Text index consists of four basic tables, referred to as the $I, $K, $N and $R tables respectively. Other tables are used when particular indexing options are turned on. The tables exist within the schema of the text index owner, and have names concatenated from DR$, the name of the index, and the suffix (e.g. $I)

[Oracle Text Whitepaper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/12coracletexttwp-1961244.pdf)

According to the whitepaper, these are tables used by Oracle Text.

Use the following query to get the index size. For example, I have an index called `I_ICOL1`.

```
SQL> select segment_name,bytes/1024/1024 MB from dba_segments where SEGMENT_NAME='I_ICOL1';

SEGMENT_NAME        MB
------------        ----------
I_ICOL1             .4375
```

Comment: So, I cannot group by name because I have multiple segments for one index. I should use: `SELECT sum(bytes)/1024/1024/1024 GB FROM dba_segments WHERE segment_name LIKE '%INDEX_NAME%';` and I got 2.7 GB, right?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple segments for one index? One logical object such as table or index has only one segment but can have multiple extents. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/logical.htm#CNCPT004

Comment: As you said: "The Oracle Text index consists of four basic tables, referred to as the $I, $K, $N and $R tables respectively." That's why my index is referenced multiple times in the `DBA_SEGMENTS` table.

Comment: @Pierre `LIKE '%$INDEX_NAME$%'` would be better.